Why do I have to increase the delay periodically while trying to synchronize two streams at the receiver?
I am trying to synchronize two streams at the receiver in GNU Radio.
You can see in the Picture below that I subtract the receiver signal from the signal that has been demodulated and modulated again. The result that I expect from the subtraction is zero when the two streams are synchronized.
I manage to get zero as a result with a low value of delay but after a bit I have to increase delay by one to get again zero in the output.
Why the delay is not constant in this case? Does this have anything to do with any of the blocks in between ? Or is this behavior expected when we do synchronization.
Thank you in advance.



In general, synchronization is a process that must happen continuously (or at least periodically). Things that are in sync now, will get out of sync sooner rather than later.
The exception is when you can guarantee that two processes are isochronous (they use the same exact clock) and all signal paths have deterministic, controlled delays.

Thank you for your comment!! In my example I expected the two streams to synchronize after I find the required delay value as in this example https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=QPSK_Mod_and_Demod. But even if I run everything in the same flowgraph I still have to increase the delay periodically. Maybe it is expected as you said.

I agree it would be intuitive to expect the streams to stay in sync, since it's all software running on a single computer. However, it's not really that surprising: gnuradio is multithreaded, so you have different blocks running on different cores on different threads, managed by an OS that is probably running hundreds of processes.
